# Does Python have a shortcut for creating arrays like Ruby's %w(things in array)

Tags: python, arrays, ruby

Does Python have a shortcut for creating arrays like Ruby's `%w(strings in array)`?

Python seems to make me use the longer syntax of putting `"` and `,` around everything in an array I'm creating, which is frustrating and rude.

Unfortunately I can't find any shorthand for creating arrays. Is there any mechanism built into the language for this?

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for the `split` method?

```
# ["this", "that", "other"]
x = "this that other".split()
```

As long as you can find an appropriate free delimiter, `split` can accommodate you.

```
# ["first item", "second item", "third item"]
x = "first item,second item,third item".split(",")
```

With a good text editor, and the relatively infrequent need to define such lists, I don't find the lack of special syntax particularly galling.

---

To be clear, Python does not have such a shortcut.

Comment: The string split method in many programming languages is very similar to `%w`/`%W` but there's one difference: you can escape the separator (US-ASCII SP) like this `%w[this\ that other]` which is the same as `["this that", "other"]`. The second part of the answer kinda addresses this though.

Comment: The point is, `%w` is pretty much just syntactic sugar, which Python lacks. Objectively, it's unnecessary; subjectively, one can argue that its convenience outweighs the additional complexity it adds to the language. Python's developers decided that something similar was not. (I believe that the Perl equivalent--`qw/this that other/`--predates Python, and both predate Ruby.)

Comment: @chepner, yes, Perl's `qw` is much older.